# Output file into Excel line by line

Tags: c++, excel, csv

The user inputs a string separated by spaces. The code runs a permutation and exports the file into a .csv file. The problem is that the code output in the C++ output window does not match the code formatting in the .csv file. The code in the .csv file is one large string of the C++ output window. The .csv output does not account for the separate lines in the code output.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;
int main() {
    cout << "Type in string (separate by spaces).\n" << endl;
    int r;
    string t;
    getline(cin, t);
    /* Put the line in a stringstream and extract word by word back */
    istringstream iss(t);
    string words;
    vector<string> n;
    while (iss >> words) {
        n.push_back(words);
    }
    std::ofstream output_file;
    output_file.open("C:/Users/UserName/Documents/output2.csv");
    cout << "\n";
    int ctr;
    for (ctr = 0; ctr < n.size(); ctr++){
            do {
                for (auto i = n.begin(); i != n.end() - ctr; ++i)
                std::cout << *i << ' ';
                cout << endl;
                for (auto i = n.begin(); i != n.end() - ctr; ++i)
                output_file << *i << ' ';
            } while (std::next_permutation(n.begin(), n.end()));
        }
    output_file.close();
    system("pause");
}
```

Here is the output from the C++ output window:

```
I like strawberries

I like strawberries
I strawberries like
like I strawberries
like strawberries I
strawberries I like
strawberries like I
I like
I strawberries
like I
like strawberries
strawberries I
strawberries like
I
I
like
like
strawberries
strawberries
```

Here is the .csv Excel file output (all in cell a1):

```
I like strawberries I strawberries like like I strawberries like strawberries I strawberries I like strawberries like I I like I strawberries like I like strawberries strawberries I strawberries like I I like like strawberries strawberries
```

My ultimate goal is to get the C++ output window to be the same in the .csv file. This works when I manually copy and paste the code into the .csv file, but that is impractical for large strings.

Comment: You have `cout << endl;` for putting the newline into the console and then flushing it so you need to do something similar for the outpt file. It might be as easy as `output_file << '\n';`

Comment: I did that before, but the code separates each word into the csv cells (in one column). Not the same as the C++ output window, where there are sentences. @JerryJeremiah

Comment: Wait?  So writing a newline into the csv file doesn't work?

Comment: I thought that was the solution before. @JerryJeremiah

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is lack of a newline in the right place. You need to write all the words of the current permutation, then (when you've finished the "sentence") a new-line to separate that one from the next.

A simplified version that only writes out the permutations of the complete set of words (and has your test case hard-coded) looks something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

using namespace std;
int main() {
    istringstream iss("I like strawberries");

    vector<string> n { std::istream_iterator<std::string>(iss), { } };

    std::ofstream output_file("c:/c/source/output2.csv");

    std::sort(n.begin(), n.end());

    do {
        for (auto const &s : n)
            output_file << s << ' ';
        output_file << "\n";
    } while (std::next_permutation(n.begin(), n.end()));
}
```

Note the addition of the call to `std::sort`. This is necessary for `std::next_permutation` to return `false` at the right time (it returns false when the next permutation will place the items in sorted order, so you get all permutations if and only if it's in sorted order before the first call). As it happens, your test case starts out sorted, but you can't depend on that in general.

A quick test with Excel shows this opening with one "sentence" per cell.